# How to check if an element does NOT have a specific class?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

How do I check if there isn't a class. For example, I know how to check to see if it has the class "test", but how do I check to see if it doesn't have the class "test"?

```
if($(this).hasClass("test")){
}
```

Answer (score 552, accepted):

```
if (!$(this).hasClass("test")) {
```

Comment: In the TIMTOWTDI vein, here's a horrible solution: `if($(this).is(":not(.test)"))` >:)

Comment: In case anyone's wondering: There Is More Than One Way To Do It, But Sometimes Consistency Is Not A Bad Thing Either.

Answer (score 175):

sdleihssirhc's answer is of course the correct one for the case in the question, but just as a reference if you need to select elements that don't have a certain class, you can use the [not](http://api.jquery.com/not/) selector:

```
// select all divs that don't have class test
$( 'div' ).not( ".test" );
$( 'div:not(.test)' );  // <-- alternative
```

Comment: IMHO your answer is best. If sdleihssirhc's answer is correct than this question had nothing to do with jQuery and would be better formulated as 'given some condition, how do I test that that condition is NOT true in Javascript'. What we want with jQuery is operate on whole collections of DOM elements just as easy as we can on single objects. Your answer provides just that solution. +1

Comment: @byronyasgur In the context of the original question the poster wanted to test if a certain known element did not have the class. This code selects all elements that don't have the class, so it wouldn't solve the poster's problem. I don't remember why I posted this in the first place.

Answer (score 20):

Select element (or group of elements) having class "abc", not having class "xyz":

```
    $('.abc:not(".xyz")')
```

When selecting regular CSS you can use `.abc:not(.xyz)`.

Answer (score 15):

You can try this:

```
<div id="div1" class="myClass">there is a class</div>
<div id="div2"> there is no class2 </div>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#div2").not('.myClass');  // do not have `myClass` class.
});
```

Comment: This answer doesn't add any value to the page, it was posted 7 years ealier. Please do never post code-only and duplicate content.

Answer (score 8):

use the .not() method and check for an attribute:

```
$('p').not('[class]');
```

Check it here: http://jsfiddle.net/AWb79/

Comment: This is completely wrong. Brackets are not for classes but used for selectors identifying attributes.

Comment: Actually it's completely right. The '[class]' is correctly identifying the attribute of (not) having a class.

Comment: @Misterparker classes are attributes.

Comment: this checks if the attribute is present, not the case if an element has a specific class, as in class value

Answer (score 5):

Try this.

```
if (!$(object).hasClass("className")) {


}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are more complex scenarios where this doesn't work. What if you want to select an element with class A that doesn't contain elements with class B.
You end up needing something more like:

[If parent element does not contain certain child element; jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10168248/if-parent-element-does-not-contain-certain-child-element-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

reading through this 6yrs later and thought I'd also take a hack at it, also in the *TIMTOWTDI vein*...:D, hoping it isn't incorrect 'JS etiquette'.

I usually set up a var with the condition and then refer to it later on..i.e;

```
// var set up globally OR locally depending on your requirements
var hC;

function(el) {
  var $this = el;
  hC = $this.hasClass("test");

  // use the variable in the conditional statement
  if (!hC) {
    //
  }
}
```

Although I should mention that I do this because I mainly use the conditional ternary operator and want clean code. So in this case, all i'd have is this:

```
hC ? '' : foo(x, n) ;
   // OR -----------
!hC ? foo(x, n) : '' ;
```

...instead of this:

```
$this.hasClass("test") ? '' : foo(x, n) ;
   // OR -----------
(!$this.hasClass("test")) ? foo(x, n) : '' ;
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know why, but the accepted answer didn't work for me. Instead this worked:

```
if ($(this).hasClass("test") !== false) {}
```

Comment: This actually checks if it DOES have class "test". In order to check if it DOES NOT have class "test", you would need to have "=== false", or "!==true" instead of "!== false".