# jQuery show div only if has class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some problems with show/hide element. I have 2 popups on one page and I need hide one popup if another popup has class.
For example:

```
<body class="home">
  <div class="popup main"></div>
  <div class="popup"></div>
</body>
```

So, if **body.home** has **.main** I need to show only **.main** popup and hide or remove another **.popup**.

I'va tried

```
if ($('.home').find('.main')) {
     $('.home').find('.main').show();
     $('.home').find('.popup').remove();
}
```

But it does not working as I need, because in some reason I'll have code only with one popup block

```
<body class="home">
  <div class="popup"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7841048/how-to-check-if-an-element-does-not-have-a-specific-class

Comment: you can also use like this $( '.home .popup' ).hide().filter('.main').show();

Comment: @raghavendra incase he have only one popup without `.main` class, that time he want to show

Comment: @Sathish you don't think yourself op has to say that. it might the case we could have provided a better solution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just try this,

```js
if($(".popup").hasClass('main')){
   $(".popup").hide();
   $(".main").show();
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body class="home">
  <div class="popup main">main</div>
  <div class="popup">another</div>
</body>
```

Comment: twice popup is hiding

Comment: please read this notice: but in this case I'll have a problem if main doesn't exist. For example: if I have 2 different popups together I should show only one with some class like main, but if I have only one popup I should show it anyway

Comment: @raghavendra try the snippet

Comment: @oleg yes, incase you have only one popup it will show

Comment: yes, thanks! I did some minor changes for my needs, but your example is really helpful

Answer (score 2):

```
$( '.home .popup' ).not( ".main" ).remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want something like this:

```
$('.popup.main').length && 
$('.popup').show().not('.main').remove() || 
$('.popup').show();
```

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/ch42unvg/)

---

The above code is basically a "shortcut" of this:

```
// if there's a popup with class .main:
if($('.popup.main').length){
    // show it:
    $('.popup.main').show();
    // and remove the one without class .main:
    $('.popup').not('.main').remove();

// else, if there's no popup with class .main:
}else{
    // show the .popup:
    $('.popup').show();
}
```

Comment: but in this case I'll have a problem if `main` doesn't exist. For example: if I have 2 different popups together I should show only one with some class like `main`, but if I have only one popup I should show it anyway.

Comment: @Oleg, Yes, I did not read the question carefully. Updated answer

Answer (score 0):

check with `hasClass()`

```
if ($('.home .popup').hasClass('main')) {
  $('.home .popup').hide();
  $('.home .main').show();
}
```

This will hide all popups, then show only that has `.main` class

[Working pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BNgPJM?editors=101)

**Edit**

ok this in not working when .home has only one child.
Try solving this with `css`

```
.home .popup:not(.main) {
  display: none;
}
.home .popup:only-child {
  display: block !important;
}
```

with this code you only have to add/remove `.main` class to manage visibility

[Working pen with css](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BNgPJM)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show/hide element, use `jQuery.hide()` or `jQuery.show()`. If you use `jQuery.remove()` then u don't have chance to do it again because it was removed from DOM tree.