# checking particular class in all elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to console.log() a message when all li elements have "valid" class. Currently its connected by keyUp function to my inputs. My jQuery code below doesnt work. Thanks

HTML:

```
<input class="confirmPwInput" type="password" name="confirm_password">
<input class="newPwInput" type="password" name="new_password">

<ul id="#pswd_info">
  <li id="letter" class="invalid">At least
    <strong>one letter</strong>
  </li>
  <li id="capital" class="invalid">At least
    <strong>one capital letter</strong>
  </li>
  <li id="number" class="invalid">At least
    <strong>one number</strong>
  </li>
  <li id="length" class="invalid">Be at least
    <strong>10 characters</strong>
  </li>
  <li id="match" class="invalid">
    <strong>Passwords must match</strong>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Javascript:

```
$('.newPwInput,.confirmPwInput').keyup(function () {
  $('#pswd_info li').each(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('valid')){ 
      $(this).addClass('valid')
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Your code logic says *"If this has class `valid`, then add class `valid`"*...

Comment: I don't see `#pswd_info` in your markup. Is it on an ancestor element that isn't shown?

Comment: sorry i forgot. edited

Comment: @TylerRoper is spot on. Redundant logic. Instead of adding class, console log `$(this)` instead.

Comment: Thanks Tyler, how can i check all of them has class "valid"?

Comment: `#pswd_info ul` !== `ul#pswd_info`.

Comment: why do i get downvotes? i came here to search better answers to my "redundant logic".

Comment: `<ul id="#pswd_info">`  Take the `#` out of your markup.  `#` is used in the selector to denote it's an id.  You do not put it in your actual markup.  This is causing the element to not be found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search your markup for `li` tags that do not have the `.valid` class set. If there's none, all `li`s are considered valid.

```
if($('li:not(.valid)').length === 0) {
   // Everything's valid
}
```

*Edit:* If you don't want to check **all** `li`-tags on your page, be more specific about the elements, like `#pswd_info li` to inspect list elements inside an element in `#pswd_info`.

Source: [How to check if an element does NOT have a specific class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7841048/how-to-check-if-an-element-does-not-have-a-specific-class), https://api.jquery.com/length/

Comment: `size()` has been deprecated since jQuery 1.8. Use `.length` instead.

Comment: Thanks @TylerRoper, totally overlooked that

Comment: I am wondering in your answer,what's the difference between `==` and `===`?

Comment: @lucumt - In this case, nothing, because `length` and `0` are both numbers. In the general case, if the types of the operands are not the same, `==` will use type coercion to try to find equality anyway, so (for instance) `"" == 0` is true. `===` won't try to coerce, operands of different types are never `===` each other. But when the types of the operands are the same, `==` and `===` do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to console.log() a message when all li elements have "valid" class.

So you want to log a message when there is no `li` without "valid" class.

Then just check if the selector `li:not(.valid)` returns an empty list.

with vanilla JS, you get something like that :

```
if (document.querySelectorAll('li:not(.valid)').length === 0) {
    console.log("Your message");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to console.log() a message when all li elements have "valid" class

you can compare 2 jQuery selectors content, to check if they all have a certain class, something like

```
if( $('#pswd_info ul li').length == $('#pswd_info ul li.valid').length){
    console.log('all li inside #pswd_info ul has the valid class');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't show any logic being used to actually add the tags, but this will show when all (5) fields are `.valid`. However, this exact one is not really sustainable or scalable - it'd be better to remove the invalid tag, and look for the number of fields with `.invalid` to equal `0`.

```js
$('.newPwInput,.confirmPwInput').keyup(function() {
  var validCount = $('#pwd_info ul li.valid').length; // Count how many elements have the valid tag
  console.log(validCount);
  if (validCount == 5) {
    console.log('All fields are valid');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="confirmPwInput" type="password" name="confirm_password">
<input class="newPwInput" type="password" name="new_password">


<ul id="#pswd_info">
  <li id="letter" class="invalid">At least
    <strong>one letter</strong>
  </li>
  <li id="capital" class="invalid">At least
    <strong>one capital letter</strong>
  </li>
  <li id="number" class="invalid">At least
    <strong>one number</strong>
  </li>
  <li id="length" class="invalid">Be at least
    <strong>10 characters</strong>
  </li>
  <li id="match" class="invalid">
    <strong>Passwords must match</strong>
  </li>
</ul>
```