# Execute some code if a div does not contain an element with a given class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to create an `if` condition that will check if the `.st-footer--navigation` element does not contain a div `.st--footer-column`. How can I write it in JS code?

```js
let groups = document.getElementsByClassName("st-footer--navigation")

if (...) {
  for (let i of groups) {
    let childrens = i.children;
    let stFooterColumn = document.createElement("div");

    stFooterColumn.classList.add("st--footer-column");

    while (childrens.length) {
      stFooterColumn.appendChild(childrens[0])
    }

    i.appendChild(stFooterColumn)
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if an element does NOT have a specific class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7841048/how-to-check-if-an-element-does-not-have-a-specific-class)

Comment: do you have multiple elements with "st-footer--navigation" class or only one element in html page

Answer (score 1):

You can use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

```
if(!document.querySelectorAll(".st-footer--navigation div.st--footer-column").length)
```

**CASE 1: When element `.st-footer--navigation` contains div with class `.st--footer-column`**

```js
 if(!document.querySelectorAll(".st-footer--navigation div.st--footer-column").length) {
  console.log("if executed");
 } else {
  console.log("else executed"); // else will be executed
 }
```

```html
<div class="st-footer--navigation">
  <div class="st--footer-column">

  </div>
</div>
```

**CASE 2: When element `.st-footer--navigation` does not have div with class `.st--footer-column`**

```js
if(!document.querySelectorAll(".st-footer--navigation div.st--footer-column").length) {
  console.log("if executed");  // if will be executed
 } else {
  console.log("else executed");
 }
```

```html
<div class="st-footer--navigation">

</div>
```