# Hide parent, display child if parent lacks specific class

Tags: css, visibility

On my website, I have a fullscreen header with a navigation bar inside. Both contain a mix of text, icons, etc., and appear above a "main content" section. I can add a class `.p-X` to either `#splash` or `#nav` (X = page number, e.g. `.p-1` for page 1 (URL `INDEX/page/1`) and `.p-2` for page 2 (URL `INDEX/page/2`)) in order to display both `#splash` and `#nav` on page 1, but hide `#splash` and still display `#nav` on pages 2+. What is the most efficient way to do this? CSS and jQuery solutions okay. I've tried the visibility answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5521387) and JJJ's selector [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7841048) (might've misapplied the latter though). Thanks!

EDIT: The current accepted answer would not allow me to preserve the curved edge on #nav (there'd be white space between `#splash`'s image and `#nav`'s top edge). I can live with it removed, but I wonder if there's a way to preserve it.

```css
#splash {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background:#e00;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
}

.icon {
    width: 128px;
    height: 128px;
    background: #ddd;
    margin: auto 0 0.5rem 0;
}

#splash .info {
    max-width: 700px;
    margin: 0 auto auto auto;
    background: #ddd;
}

#nav {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    z-index: 5;
    border-radius: 30% 30% 0% 0%; /* curved top if #splash is shown; curved bottom if not */
}

#content {
    height: 100vh;
    overflow-x: hidden:
    overflow-y: auto;
    background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
    <section id="splash" class="p-X">
    hide this on pages not 1
        <div class="icon">hide this on pages not 1</div>
        <div class="info">hide this on pages not 1</div>
        <section id="nav">
            sticks to top via JS when #splash is scrolled out/not displayed; display this on every page
        </section>
    </section>
    <section id="content">
        scrollable main content; display new content on different pages
    </section>
```

Comment: `display: none` will make the element behave like it never existed, `visibility: hidden` just hides it away visually (but the element still has size).
Besides that, I find your question confusing. It is unclear what you are trying to do. Please add a reproducible example and please explain/show what the end result should look like. You can use the snippet for that.

Comment: @F.Müller Snippet added.

Comment: What else is in the `splash` section? It seems like you could hide the `icon` and `info` no problem.

Comment: @disinfor, #splash contains a customizable background image, a clickable image icon, and info text. ideally, #nav would have curved edges which switch from top to bottom depending on whether it's at the bottom of #splash or at the top of the window. The main issue stems from the fact that I have #nav inside #splash; thus, hiding #splash hides #nav too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to display a child of an element when the parent is hidden.

Try moving the #nav out of the #splash so it's no longer a child of #nav. Then to achieve the same look, place #nav after the #splash in the markup and use `#nav { background-color: transparent }` so you can see the main content underneath, and also use `#splash {height: calc(100vh - HEIGHTOF#NAV)}` to make the #nav stick to the bottom.

Set your scroll position rules in JS to act on the #nav instead of #splash.

Now you're free to hide or show the #splash section without if affecting the #nav

Comment: Apologies for not having a snippet at first. For sake of preserving #splash's flex margins (which put the nav at its bottom) and some JS functionality (e.g. "#nav sticks to top if #splash is scrolled offscreen"), I would prefer not to do this yet, but I agree it's a possible solution. Are the answers here (particularly answer 2, which I tried) really no longer valid? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5521387

Comment: Those are valid still, but if you use visibility: hidden; then the splash will still take up the space at the top of the document. I'm assuming on pages other than 1 you want the nav to be at the top and the #splash hidden. I've updated my answer for a simple solution I think should't take long to implement.

Comment: Here, I made a a quick and dirty codepen to show you how you can achieve the desired frontend. Check it out: https://codepen.io/_codemanezeta/pen/GRZjxZM

Comment: Please give my answer an upvote if you found it helpful. Good luck. :]

Comment: Cleans up my sticky function too! I've marked this as answer for now, unless another answer comes along that preserves #nav inside #splash OR at least the curved margins. My #nav also had curved margins (the curved side switches from top edge (over splash image) to bottom (when splash is off-window) which wouldn't work on the pen.

Answer (score 0):

Set it up so that the `#splash` is hidden by default. Then, if it's on page one, make `#splash` a block element.

```
#splash {
    display: none;
}
.p1 #splash {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Apologies for not having a snippet earlier.