# check if an element does not contain a class in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Hello friends I have this code that works well for me to check if my element contains a certain class, but I want to achieve the opposite, that it checks me when this class does not contain the element.

```
if (document.querySelector(".header").classList.contains("no-sticky")) {
      alert();
    }
```

Comment: Why not use the *not* symbol `!`

Comment: Write it like: `if (!document.querySelector(".header").classList.contains("no-sticky")) {
      alert();
    }`

Comment: just to be pedantic and for brevity, there is the `else` also ‍♂️

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if an element does NOT have a specific class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7841048/how-to-check-if-an-element-does-not-have-a-specific-class)

Comment: Hi Friends, exactly where should I use the "!" I tried putting it before "! .classList.contains" and it didn't work :(

Comment: I’m surprised you were not able to find the solution in whatever search you did prior.

Comment: This link: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5898656/check-if-an-element-contains-a-class-in-javascript)

Comment: @poPaTheGuru  Thanks friend that worked for me. I am very grateful to you

Answer (score 5):

Just put exclamation mark in front of the condition.

````
if (!document.querySelector(".header").classList.contains("no-sticky")) {
      alert();
    }```
````

Comment: Thanks friend this worked for me, I know it is something very simple but I do not know much pure javascript, I thank you very much this was driving me crazy

Comment: Thanks! It's working for me now with `if (!x.classList.contains("my-class"))` but I'm curious as to why `if x.classList.contains("my-class")!==true` didn't work, and also why `if x.classList.contains("my-class")===false` didn't work. If anyone is willing to explain why, comments are welcome and appreciated.